# Java "java.awt.Window" Array add Item at position 0

Tags: java, arrays, window

I have following code:

```
java.awt.Window win[] = java.awt.Window.getWindows();
for(int i=0;i<win.length;i++){
    win[i].dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(win[i], WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
}
```

But my problem is that the first open window is closed at first. But I have to turn it around. How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean turn it around?

Comment: The first item must be the last and the last must be the first...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize `i = (win.length - 1)`
and then make `i` count backwards instead. End the loop when `i >= 0`.

Your question isn't very well worded, but if I understand correctly, this might work.

Like this:

```
java.awt.Window win[] = java.awt.Window.getWindows();
for(int i = (win.length - 1); i >= 0; i--){
    win[i].dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(win[i], WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
}
```

Comment: I get an error:Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9
 at

Comment: Try now, I think it should be the array length minus 1, as I have updated it.